# How to copy a document including subcollections in Firestore with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in Firebase Firestore with documents, lets say: `Products`.
Every Product could have multiple subcolletions like `Pictures`, `Specifications`, `Manufactures`, etc.

Now I would like to copy a product **including** all the subcollections and its documents.
I' able to copy the Product quite easy, but getting the subcollections and there documents, seems  to be quite impossible yet.

Is this possible to do from Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing that type of data on the product document because it's data about the product. However, if for some reason you need to store that data in sub-collections you really have two options...

1. If you don't know what the sub-collections are you could write a recursive function to get the first document, read the sub-collections off that, get all those documents, and repeat until there are no more sub-collections left.
2. If you do know what the sub-collections you're getting are, just sent multiple requests.

```dart
final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
final results = await Future.wait([
  db.collection('products').doc(docID).get(),
  db.collection('products/$docID/pictures').get()
])
```

Comment: Hi @Ben, thanks for your answer. I'm looking for a recursive function, because as the moment of copying the document I don't know the amount of sub-collections